# How to hide the CMD console from this code?

Tags: c#, process, start-process

How to hide the console from within this code? Currently the cmd console is shown everytime I run this code.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{            
    String applicationName = "cmd.exe";
    // launch the application
    ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
    ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(applicationName, out procInfo);

}
```

How can I execute a *.bat file from here? Can I simply can substitute the "cmd.exe" with "xxx.bat"?

Comment: isn't the code only opening a cmd?

Comment: so how is asking here easier than trying it?

Comment: yes. but i will change the 'cmd.exe' to my own 'app.exe'..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a System Reference to the code;

```
using System Diagnostics;
```

Then use this code to Hide the CMD Window and run.

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "Your arguments";
cmd.Start();
```

Comment: the variable `cmd` is a process variable that we created `Process cmd = new Process`. try to add `using System.Diagnostics` to your solution. note also that you have to change `"Your arguments"` to the arguments that you want to pass to that process

Comment: but I need to use the StartProcessAndBypassUAC function. how?

Comment: I don't own that function, and the function code is hidden from me! however you should check the properties of the `ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION` since your `StartProcessAndBypassUAC` method returning it "`out procInfo`".

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the Process Class instead of the ApplicationLoader (I´ve never heard of that class, is it a custom class?)

Code Example:

```
 using System.Diagnostics;

 Process pr = new Process();
 pr.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 pr.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 pr.Arguments = "xxx.bat";
 pr.Start();
```